# Jquery toggle images having same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

I have number of images in one drop dawn (Bootstrap),
Now I want that, when i click on one drop dawn value, images should be change. but I have all image with same id, because drop dawn value are change dynamically.

When I Use My code, only first image is toggle,
i.e : if I click name 1 or name 6, only name 1's image toggle and another image not displaying.

Here Is My Code and jS Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/tutorialdrive/4n7xR/)

**HTML**

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Drop Dawn<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(0);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(1);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(2);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(3);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(4);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(5);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fnShowHide(6);"><img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" id="icon_green_tick"/><img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" id="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

**And My Jquery Code**

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
      $('#icon_green_tick').toggle();
});
```

---

Is there any way to create array of ID using Jquery ?

---

I don't want to toggle all image at once., toggle noly image where I click, i.e. : name 2, name 6 etc.

Comment: Duplicate IDs are invalid. Use a class instead.

Comment: Ids must be unique for each context page!!! That's all, use class instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you should change your IDs I think this is what you're looking for

```
$(".dropdown-menu li").click(function () {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4n7xR/3/

Answer (score 1):

As already said in your Q comments, Duplicate ID are **bad**

<kbd>**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4n7xR/6/)**</kbd>

Simply replace `id="icon_green_tick"` with `class="icon_green_tick"` and use accordingly in jQ:

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'li', function ( e ) {
      e.preventDefault();
      fnShowHide( $(this).index() );
      $(this).find('.icon_green_tick').toggle();
});
```

Additionally you don't need to use inline JS inside your HTML to call your `fnShowHide` function:

```
<li>
   <a href="#">
    <img src = "http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/silk2/tick.png" class="icon_green_tick"/>
    <img src = "http://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/lynx/22x22/actions/dialog-close.png" style = "display:none;" class="icon_green_tick"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;name 1
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: thanks @roXon, but Spokey answer first, so I vote him up,
thanks once again.

Comment: I know that but Spokey also do the same, so..
and I know you lost your time, so I vote your answer up double. :)

Comment: @ShivamPandya :) no need to :) added more info to my answer, kudos to Spokey for being faster. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

*You should definitely consider changing your HTML so that you do not have multiple elements with the same ID*

However, if you absolutely cannot modify the HTML, you can use:

```
$('img[id="icon_green_tick"]').toggle();
```

to toggle all images with the `id` attribute matching `"icon_green_tick"`.

Comment: I don't want to toggle all images at a time, I want to toggle image where Click, i.e name 2, name 4 etc.

Answer (score 1):

**You should assign multiple form elements the same class but not the same id.** Do what you are doing but using **class** attributes instead of **ids**